# How to automatically close an OS X apps after not being used for a number of minutes?

Tags: macos, accessibility

How to automatically close an OS X apps after not being used for a number of minutes??

I am looking for a way to auto-close apps that are not used (focused at least) for a number of minutes, a number of minutes configured for each one.

Why? While freeing up memory is not so important in my case, decluttering the number of opened windows on OS X it is.

I am currently using ControlPlane to automate starting or stopping of apps based on different profiles and if there is a way to extend it to do that too it would be great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use Quitter by Marco Arment: https://marco.org/apps

> [image: Quitter screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

I believe that OSX does this automatically, via AppNap. You don't need to pay a third party company for this feature, since Lion.

Comment: Not really, that does suspect apps. It does not work with all apps and worse, it does not unclutter your bar, so it does not help with focusing. It does help a little bit only on resources.

Comment: It's supposed to do this, but the only app I've ever seen actually OS X close down is Preview. (Presumably AppNap is still doing other energy-saving stuff to background apps other than completely shutting them down, though.)

Comment: In theory, all apps would be written to take advantage of this self quitting behavior. In practice, many apps do not and more frustratingly, the apps that most need to be written well are written to not behave well.